# How do I make a Safari window active using AppleScript (elegantly)?

Tags: applescript

While one can simulate command-shift-` using System Events to change windows in Safari, is there no better way to do this with AppleScript? I can change the index of Safari's windows, this changes their ordering on the screen but does not make them active. Suppose you have two Safari windows containing about:blank -- how could you bring the one in the back to the front and make it active?

Granted, command-shift-` works, so maybe there only needs to be one way to skin this cat.

Comment: how do you change the indexes ? can i see that code ?

Comment: Ack, I deleted it, but the Safari window element has a read-writable index variable. You can grab the Safari application, grab its windows, then tell a window to set its index to 1. This brings it to the front, without changing the focus window.

Answer (score 10):

I also noticed that changing the index does reorder the windows however the new window does not actually come to the front. By playing around I found you can fix that by playing with the "visible" property...

```
tell application "Safari"
    set theWindows to windows
    set win2 to item 2 of theWindows
    tell win2
        set visible to false
        set visible to true
        set index to 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: That's pretty cool. I'm almost shocked that there isn't a settable "focus" parameter at the window level.