# Get screenshot of hidden window Python Mac OS

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to take a screenshot of a background window on Mac OS using python.
I can currently only get a screenshot of visible screens.

```
x1,y1,width,height =pygetwindow.getWindowGeometry('Google Chrome ')
x2=x1+width
y2=y1+height

im = pyautogui.screenshot(path)
im =im.crop((x1,y1,x2,y2))
im.save(path)
im.show()
```

Comment: When a window is hidden, its pixels do not exist.  What you see is what you can get.  When the window is made visible again, the application has to go redraw everything.  Put another way, what you ask is impossible.

Comment: As @TimRoberts said, I think the best way is to (1) bring the hidden window back to the foreground, (2) get the screenshot, and (3) move back the window to the background. Some Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173514/applescript-bring-window-to-foreground https://gist.github.com/qur2/5729056

Answer (score -1):

I cannot comment, but I'm studying I too the argument. Unfortunately my MacBook's macOS version is locked up to 11, but if you have 12 or better yet 10.13 [beta] you can try with this new library: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/screencapturekit/capturing_screen_content_in_macos

If you can update us on this!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32207036)

Comment: @DavidT I'm sorry, but I have not recent enough macOS for testing the answer. In any case stackoverflow can rely on archive.org